# Python > Selenium + CSV: Webdriver to read, visit all links in .csv file

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

This question is about using a webdriver (*"ChromeDriver", Selenium*) to:

> 1) Look-up a *.csv* file; and 
> 2) Visit all links in the file,
>   one at a time, until the list is over.

I've put together a simple code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Assume *link.csv* contains the following sites:

• www.google.com

• www.wikipedia.org

• www.yahoo.com

```
f = open('link.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
reader = csv.reader(f)

for line in reader:
    driver.get(line[0])
    time.sleep(10)


f.close()
```

... the following message was raised:

```
"selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument"
```

Appreciate your help and patience in explaining what had actually gone wrong :)

Comment: If you are using the for loop, then why are you accessing element at the 0th index? I'm talking about this line `driver.get(line[0])`

Comment: Your code looks fine.Just change all the url in CSV file like `https://www.google.com
https://www.wikipedia.org
https://www.yahoo.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t use an index with line, just do:

```
for line in reader:
    Driver.get(line)
```